# SecureRandom self-seeding

Tags: java, random

I found a lot of examples about the [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) class that look like this:

```
Random random = new SecureRandom();
int randomInteger = random.nextInt();
```

or like this:

```
try
{
    Random random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    int randomInteger = random.nextInt();
}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException exception)
{
    // ...
}
```

or something similar.

However, both [`SecureRandom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#SecureRandom%28%29) and [`SecureRandom.getInstance(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29) have this part in their documentation:

> The returned `SecureRandom` object has not been seeded. To seed the returned object, call the `setSeed` method. If `setSeed` is not called, the first call to `nextBytes` will force the `SecureRandom` object to seed itself. This self-seeding will not occur if `setSeed` was previously called.

So, the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) object is never seeded at creation time in the above examples. The documentation of [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) (from the `Random` class documentation, it's not overridden in `SecureRandom`) states:

> The method `nextInt` is implemented by class `Random` as if by:

```
public int nextInt() {
    return next(32);
}
```

So, there is no call to a [`nextBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#nextBytes%28byte%5B%5D%29) method, neither the documentation for the [`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#next%28int%29) method in `SecureRandom` says anything about seeding.

My questions are: are the above `Random` objects seeded for sure? Are all those examples wrong or am I missing something? Can I safely use such an unseeded random numbers generator?

As correctly pointed out in a comment, looking at the [source code](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/security/SecureRandom.java.html) it seems like `next` calls `nextBytes`, therefore initializing the seed, however this is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: `next(32)` calls `nextBytes`.

Comment: @assylias: What makes you think that? I don't see such a call in the source code of JDK 1.7?

Comment: @assylias: looking at [this source code](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/security/SecureRandom.java.html) (line 472) it seems true, however it is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Yes, SecureRandom overrides next(int) to use nextBytes.

Comment: @assylias, you could post an answer to this question.

Comment: @AlexD I'm not a Java language lawyer, but is such an undocumented implementation detail enough to be sure that those examples are correct? Couldn't it be changed?

Comment: @effeffe I think the introduction to the javadoc is clear enough that you can count on that to happen (or something similar).

Comment: Since @assylias didn't post an answer, I did so, just to wrap this question up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Sun's JRE, can a `SecureRandom` be used without seeding? No, for the reason @assylias pointed out in his comment. `nextInt` calls `nextBytes`, which ensures the `SecureRandom` is seeded.

Could an alternate implementation of the Java platform provide a `SecureRandom` which could be used without seeding, while still conforming to the documented interface? Yes. Would that be bad? Oh yes. Would any implementer be so stupid as to do such a thing? Probably not. Is it something Java programmers need to worry about? No.

Comment: Is the documentation missing something? Probably yes.

Comment: two months latter it is learned that [google didn't bother to seed SecureRandom on android phones which allowed thousands of dollars to be stolen](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/08/google-confirms-critical-android-crypto-flaw-used-in-5700-bitcoin-heist/).